# ReactJS Carousel with SliderJS

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to create a carousel with two rows, and 4 columns on each row. I am trying to use SliderJS to do so, however I am experiencing some strange behaviour: the width of the cells seems to expand for some reason.

I am using more or less of the exact same code as the demos do on the SliderJS website

Attached is [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTBXZ9lqOdY) of what is occurring, and my code below.

Expected behaviour is a carousel with 2 rows and 4 columns, but as you can see in the video, the carousel seems to be expanding to the infinity!

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
 
// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/grid";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
 
import "./carousel.scss";
 
// import required modules
import { Grid, Pagination } from "swiper";
 
export default function Carousel() {
    return (
        <>
            <Swiper
                slidesPerView={3}
                grid={{
                    rows: 2,
                }}
                spaceBetween={30}
                modules={[Grid, Pagination]}
                className="mySwiper"
            >
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 5</SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
        </>
    );
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
 
.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
 
.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  height: calc((100% - 30px) / 2) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sunset-8dgr4y?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/grid";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

import "./carousel.css";

// import required modules
import { Grid, Pagination } from "swiper";

export default function Carousel() {
  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        slidesPerView={3}
        grid={
          {
            // rows: 2,
          }
        }
        spaceBetween={30}
        // modules={[Grid, Pagination]}
        className="mySwiper"
      >
        <SwiperSlide>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
        </SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
          <p>Hello wolr</p>
        </SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, now all that's displayed is one really wide column with no text. The text briefly flashes for a second then disappears

Comment: You could at least explain what is it you fixed to help OP and others that might find this question.

Answer (score 0):

Removing it from flexbox fixed issue.

Unsure why swiperJS glitches like so in the flexbox

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).